# Unsupported Media Type 415 Error in Angular 7 & .NET Core API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm passing in a selected row to delete in my Angular Application using selection on a material data table. For some reason though, I'm getting a 415 error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, either on the server or the client side, but I'm not sure even if I'm passing the correct object.

What's the issue here? I'm using Angular 7 for the client and making the API in .NET Core

**ActionsController.cs** **.NET Core**

```
 [HttpDelete("deleteRow")]
    public Msg DeleteRows(string sessionId, T table, Tag[] rows)
    {
        try
        {
            UserState userState = GetUserState(sessionId);

            Msg m = CheckTableAccess(sessionId, table, TableAccessLevel.ReadModifyCreateDelete, userState);

            if (m.IsNotOk)
                return m;

            if (table == T.Action)
            {
                foreach (Tag t in rows)
                {
                    m = CheckUpdatableAction(sessionId, rows[0]);
                    if (m.IsNotOk)
                        return m;
                }
            }

            if (table == T.RouteStop)
            {
                XioTransaction xt = new XioTransaction(userState);
                XioWriter xwd = null;
                xwd = xt.CreateDeleteWriter(table);
                foreach (Tag t in rows)
                {
                    XioTable routeStop = new XioTable(userState, T.RouteStop);
                    Tag ownerTag = ((DbrRouteStop)routeStop.LoadSingleRow(t, C.RouteStop_RouteTag)).RouteTag;
                    xwd.DeleteRow(t, ownerTag);
                }
                xt.WriteAll();
            }
            else if (table == T.RouteEvent)
            {
                XioTransaction xt = new XioTransaction(userState);
                XioWriter xwd = null;
                xwd = xt.CreateDeleteWriter(table);

                foreach (Tag t in rows)
                {
                    XioTable routeEvent = new XioTable(userState, T.RouteEvent);
                    Tag ownerTag = ((DbrRouteEvent)routeEvent.LoadSingleRow(t, C.RouteEvent_RouteTag)).RouteTag;
                    xwd.DeleteRow(t, ownerTag);
                }
                xt.WriteAll();
            }
            else if (table == T.CompanyResource)
            {
                XioTransaction xt = new XioTransaction(userState);
                XioWriter xwd = null;
                xwd = xt.CreateDeleteWriter(table);

                foreach (Tag t in rows)
                {
                    XioTable cr = new XioTable(userState, T.CompanyResource);
                    DbrCompanyResource crRec = (DbrCompanyResource)cr.LoadSingleRow(t, C.CompanyResource_CompanyTag, C.CompanyResource_Tab);

                    XioTable xtr = new XioTable(userState, crRec.Tab);
                    // the critical where is on divisiontag and all tables that are passed in will have a divion tag
                    // luckily the code will just look at the field name
                    xtr.WhereList.Where(C.Driver_DivisionTag, ComparisonOp.EqualTo, crRec.CompanyTag);
                    xtr.LoadData();
                    if (xtr.GetAllRows().Length > 0)
                        return new Msg(M.ResourcesExistAtCompanyLevel);
                    xwd.DeleteRow(t);
                }
                xt.WriteAll();
            }
            else
                DbRow.DeleteRecursive(userState, table, rows);

            userState.Completed(LogEntryType.DeleteRows, null);
        }
        catch (MsgException e)
        {
            return e.Msg;
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            if (e.Number == 547)
            {
                return new Msg(M.CannotDeleteOwnerRowWithComponent);
            }
            else
                return new Msg(M.UnexpectedViewDeleteError, e.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Msg(M.UnexpectedViewDeleteError, e.ToString());
        }

        return Msg.Ok;
    }
```

**ViewComponent.ts**

```
    export class ViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // User Fields
  currentUser: User;
  users: User[] = [];
  currentUserSubscription: Subscription;

  loading : boolean;
  // Action Fields
  viewData: any;
  viewName: string;
  refNumber: number;
  currentActionSubscription: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  dataSource: any = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);

  defaultSort: MatSortable = {
    id: 'defColumnName',
    start: 'asc',
    disableClear: true
  };

  defaultPaginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private actionService: ActionService
  ) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'thumbs-up',
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        'assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'
      )
    );
  }

  loadAction(action: any) {

    this.loading = true;
    // If there is already data loaded into the View, cache it in the service.
    if (this.viewData) {
      this.cacheAction();
    }

    if (this.sort) {
      // If there is sorting cached, load it into the View.
      if (action.sortable) {
        // If the action was cached, we should hit this block.
        this.sort.sort(action.sortable);
      } else {
        // Else apply the defaultSort.
        this.sort.sort(this.defaultSort);
      }
    }

    if (this.paginator) {
      // If we've stored a pageIndex and/or pageSize, retrieve accordingly.
      if (action.pageIndex) {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = action.pageIndex;
      } else { // Apply default pageIndex.
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
      }

      if (action.pageSize) {
        this.paginator.pageSize = action.pageSize;
      } else { // Apply default pageSize.
        this.paginator.pageSize = 10;
      }
    }

    // Apply the sort & paginator to the View data.
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator, 4000);

    // Load the new action's data into the View:
    this.viewData = action.action;
    this.viewName = action.action.ActionName;
    this.refNumber = action.refNumber;

    // TODO: add uniquifiers/ids and use these as the sort for table

    const displayedColumns = this.viewData.Columns.map((c: { Name: any; }) => c.Name);
    displayedColumns[2] = 'Folder1';
    this.displayedColumns = ['select'].concat(displayedColumns);
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    const fetchedData = this.viewData.DataRows.map((r: { slice: (arg0: number, arg1: number) => { forEach: (arg0: (d: any, i: string | number) => any) => void; }; }) => {
      const row = {};
      r.slice(0, 9).forEach((d: any, i: string | number) => (row[this.displayedColumns[i]] = d));
      return row;
    });

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(fetchedData);
    this.loading = false;
  }

  // Stores the current Action, sort, and paginator in an ActionState object to be held in the action service's stateMap.
  cacheAction() {
    let actionState = new ActionState(this.viewData);

    // Determine the sort direction to store.
    let cachedStart: SortDirection;
    if (this.sort.direction == "desc") {
      cachedStart = 'desc';
    } else {
      cachedStart = 'asc';
    }

    // Create a Sortable so that we can re-apply this sort.
    actionState.sortable = {
      id: this.sort.active,
      start: cachedStart,
      disableClear: this.sort.disableClear
    };

    // Store the current pageIndex and pageSize.
    actionState.pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex;
    actionState.pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize;

    // Store the refNumber in the actionState for later retrieval.
    actionState.refNumber = this.refNumber;
    this.actionService.cacheAction(actionState);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribes to the action service's currentAction, populating this component with View data.
    this.actionService.currentAction.subscribe(action => this.loadAction(action));
  }

    /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
    isAllSelected() {
      const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
      const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
      return numSelected === numRows;
    }

    /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
    masterToggle() {
      this.isAllSelected()
        ? this.selection.clear()
        : this.dataSource.data.forEach((row: TableRow) => this.selection.select(row));
    }

    // Delete row functionality

    deleteRow() {
      console.log(this.selection);
      this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
        const index: number = this.dataSource.data.findIndex((d: TableRow) => d === item);
        console.log(this.dataSource.data.findIndex((d: TableRow) => d === item));
        this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
      });
      this.selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);
      this.actionService.deleteRow(this.selection).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('Success!');
      });
    }
```

**ActionsService.ts**

```
  deleteRow(selection: any): Observable<{}> {
    console.log('testing service');
// create an array of query params using the property that you use to identify a table row
    const queryParams = [selection._selection].map((row: { value: any; }) => `id=${row.value}`);
// add the query params to the url
    const url = `http://localhost:15217/actions/deleteRow`;
    return this.http.delete<any>(url);
  }
```

Comment: i dont see you sending any queryParams to the backend. and your controller looks like it suppose to take a few params, which is probably causing you issues. 
A http delete should not have a body, but the id (to delete) should be part of URL

Comment: Idk how I would fix this

Comment: ```{"errors":{"":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'Syntelic.Enterprise.SynCore.Tag[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type that can be deserialized from a JSON object.```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an http header to specify the content type for your http request body. If you are sending a json body, the header is `content-type: application/json`

You can update `actionService.ts`

```
deleteRow(selection: any): Observable<{}> {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const queryParams = [selection._selection].map((row: { value: any; }) => `id=${row.value}`);
    const url = `http://localhost:15217/actions/deleteRow`;

    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        body: {}
    } 

    return this.http.delete<any>(url, options);
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207716/discussion-on-answer-by-tejas-parnerkar-unsupported-media-type-415-error-in-angu).